# Check for nth occurrence of pattern in regular expression in Java

Tags: java, regex

I want to check nth occurrence of a particular pattern in a input string using Java regular expression. Can you please suggest how to do that?

Comment: Use Pattern and Matcher. Count the matches and discard all until you reach your target number.

Comment: He's looking for a repeating pattern, not a repeating character.

Comment: What code have you tried?  We won't help you if you haven't done any work on your own.

Comment: Not enough reputation here to reopen, but even if the question is not much detailed, I believe this question shouldn't be closed: He's specifically asking for regex. Many answers in the linked "duplicate" question doesn't apply to this question. Please think twice before hitting the "close" button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
MatchResult findNthOccurance(int n, Pattern p, CharSequence src){
    Matcher m = p.matcher(src);
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) m.find();
    return m;
}
```

Basically, it just calls `find` repeatedly on a `Matcher` obtained from the `Pattern`. Conveniently, a `Matcher` is also a `MatchResult`, so I can just return it straight up.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could do the following:

```
(?:[abc].*+){4}([abc])
```

This would match 4 occurences of either a, b or c followed by anything (non-eagerly matching such that any a, b or c would not be matched by this anything), followed by a b or c in a captured group ($1).

Simply replace [abc] by the pattern you are looking for. Replace the number in curly braces by n - 1.